# How to see if a ppa supports my distro

Tags: apt, ppa, launchpad

I often use the terminal to add a PPA to my resources list, only to find out afterwards that the PPA doesn't support my Ubuntu version. Allas, thus am greeted with an error:

```
404  Not Found
```

How can I check via terminal, if the to be added ppa supports my Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Wilf, preferably. But, if there is no terminal option. Am willing to accept a gui solutions, after a decent amount of time.

Comment: I edited my answer with a working script ;)

Comment: @MrVaykadji, nice one.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**:

The script now checks if the ppa supports your distro, and then aks for confirmation if you want to add the repo to your sources list and only then installs the packages.

**Use this at your own risk! I only tested this on two ppa's! I will not be held responsible for broken packages!**

## code:

```
#!/bin/bash


#-----------------------------------------------
#   Author      :   Imri Paloja
#   Email       :   ****.******@*****.***
#   HomePage    :   www.eurobytes.nl
#   Version     :   3.0
#   Name        :   add-ppa
#----------------------------------------------- 

# CHANGELOG
# 
# 1. Asks for confirmation if ppa supports distro.

mkdir /tmp/add-ppa/

wget --quiet "http://ppa.launchpad.net/$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/ppa://g')/ubuntu/dists" -O /tmp/add-ppa/support.html

grep "$(lsb_release -sc)" "/tmp/add-ppa/support.html" >> /tmp/add-ppa/found.txt

cat /tmp/add-ppa/found.txt | sed 's|</b>|-|g' | sed 's|<[^>]*>||g' >> /tmp/add-ppa/stripped_file.txt

if [[ -s /tmp/add-ppa/stripped_file.txt ]] ; then

echo "$(lsb_release -sc) is supported"


read -p "Do you wish to install add the ppa to your source, and install the binaries [y/n] ?"
if [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] ; then

echo "Adding it to your sources list"
sudo add-apt-repository $1

echo "Refreshing your sources list"
sudo apt-get update 

# Searching for the needed files, and installing them

wget --quiet "http://ppa.launchpad.net/$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/ppa://g')/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release -sc)/main/binary-amd64/Packages" -O /tmp/add-ppa/packages.html

grep "Package:" "/tmp/add-ppa/packages.html" >> /tmp/add-ppa/packages.txt

cat /tmp/add-ppa/packages.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' >> /tmp/add-ppa/packages_stripped_file.txt

cat /tmp/add-ppa/packages_stripped_file.txt | sed 's|Package:||g' >> /tmp/add-ppa/packages_stripped_file2.txt

sudo apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" /tmp/add-ppa/packages_stripped_file2.txt  | tr "\n" " ")

else
 exit 0
fi

else

echo "$(lsb_release -sc) is not supported"

fi;

#Cleanup

rm -r /tmp/add-ppa/
```

## usage:

**None supported ppa's**

```
./support.sh ppa:m-gehre/ppa
saucy is not supported
```

**supported ppa's**

```
./support.sh ppa:banshee-team/ppa
saucy is supported
Do you wish to add the ppa to your sources list, and install the binaries [y/n] ??

Adding it to your sources list
...
Refreshing your sources list
...
sudo apt-get install
....
```

---

See the script in action:

- [Automatic ppa checker and adder - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfXyZLpmNaE)
- [gist.github.com: blade1989 - add-ppa](https://gist.github.com/blade1989/9250261)

  - For a more up to date script, check the gist link

<sup>Improved it. Original answer by [Wilf](https://askubuntu.com/a/423323/36315)</sup>

Comment: Also nice, but I recently (haha) learn that `if [[ -n something]]` is the bash command for "if something as an output", which help reduce the temporary files created.

Comment: @MrVaykadji don't fix what isn't broken! :D

Comment: Right haha ! Nb : I updated my answer with your `lsb_release -sc` idea, and even used it on the output ;)

Comment: @MrVaykadji, quick learner! xD

Comment: In my defense, I used to know some C and (most importantly) I took some classes of "programming principles", from there, I just had to google "how to do X in bash" and voilà.

Comment: I'm too busy to any programming right now :(-  @MrVaykadji - Have fun :D

Comment: @blade19899 : sudo rm isn't necessary. It'll make you type your password. If /tmp is a root directory (I think it's not), move your temp files to $HOME, so it can be run as normal user. Don't you think ?

Comment: @MrVaykadji, thanks. i forgot to edit that out. `/tmp` you don't need to be root to edit out the file you made with this scripts.

Answer (score 7):

## A bash script to try a PPA for your distribution :

I just learned some bash *for you* haha. This works great, I'm proud (and thanks to Wilf for his answer)

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage : bash myscript ppa:something/something

# get list of ppa's supported distribution
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/ppa://g')/ubuntu/dists -O /tmp/test-ppa.tmp -q

# check if your release is in the downloaded list
RELEASE=`cat /tmp/test-ppa.tmp | grep $(lsb_release -sc)`
if [[ -n "$RELEASE" ]] ; then 
    echo "$1 will work with $(lsb_release -si) $(lsb_release -sr) $(lsb_release -sc)"
else 
    echo "$1 won't work with $(lsb_release -si) $(lsb_release -sr) $(lsb_release -sc)"
fi

# cleaning
rm /tmp/test-ppa.tmp
```

---

## Usage :

1) Copy this in a text file somewhere (in the example below it's `~/myscript`)

2) Use the command :

```
bash myscript ppa:something/something
```

> > > *Note : you can also copy that script in* /usr/bin/ *folder with* `sudo cp ~/myscript /usr/bin/ppa-test && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/ppa-test` *to use directly in command-lines* :
> > >
> > > `ppa-test ppa:something/something`

---

## Example :

(here I used : *ppa:libreoffice/ppa* with *~/myscript*)

[image: ppa-check]

Edit: *updated with blade19899's idea of using `lsb_release`*

Comment: Note : for french people, I did a fr-version with a help section and a dedicated topic : http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1504971

Answer (score 4):

I ain't tested it, but a script like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "http://ppa.launchpad.net/$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/ppa://g')/ubuntu/dists"
```

You have to run this as `./SCRIPTNAME ppa:WHATEVER/WHATEVER` - this one liner also works, but you have insert the PPA name (where `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` is):

```
echo "http://ppa.launchpad.net/$(echo ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 | sed -e 's/ppa://g')/ubuntu/dists"
```

You can then open the link in terminal (some terminals automatically show clickable links), or run it with `curl` to download it as text. It should just show the list of folders for the supported releases for the ppa.

<sub>I recently added a ppa, so I looked at that plus the Software and Updates thing and made a guess...</sub>

Comment: I should of mentioned, you have to run it as `./SCRIPTNAME ppa:WHATEVER/WHATEVER` - it does seem to work though :)

Comment: Upvoted it does work!

Answer (score 3):

Well I might have a GUI solution for you! The best way for me is PPA Manager:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

when you added ppa or ppas already added in your system, open PPA Manager and click manage ppas it will take you to new window with a list of ppas in your system click on any ppa and choose `list packages` below, if there be any packages available it will list if not you can delete it. Worked for me even yesterday I had ppa for Saucy and Trusty so list packages showed me "0" and I removed it :)

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you wanted to check out a PPA, so there's a PPA to check your PPA :D

Comment: whatever the best :)